# jQuery carousel bug in IE9, but not all instances of IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

Disclaimer: I inherited this project from another developer. I swear to god!

I'm experiencing a bug on this homepage in IE9 but not all versions of IE9. What should be happening is once the page has loaded, the main hero area should cycle through the listed events. However, IE9 does not do this. I can't reproduce the error. I have an ordinary install of IE9 in Win7. The client can, however, in what appears to be a similar environment. I've managed to reproduce it in the Browserstack version of IE9 but the effect is strange, if you click anywhere in the browser, on the page, on the scrollbars, suddenly the carousel comes to life and animates as it should.

I am at a total loss to explain/fix this. Here's the page: http://staging.tdgardenhost.com/

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Are they all running in IE9 mode or are they somehow in compat/IE7/8 etc mode?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's nothing unusual about their IE9 configuration. No compatibility mode. No different standards. No quirks mode. It's just your average install of IE9, however it was when the OS was installed.

Comment: This won't help solve the problem, but just wanted to let you know I tried it in a Win7-SP1-IE9 VM and it worked OK here too.